# How do i use the Scanner.class more than once

Tags: java, input

I am fairly new to java, and I want to know how to use the Scanner.class more than once

Meaning that i want the program to allow me to make multiple imputs.

I know that for 1 imput i can use:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String a = scanner.nextLine();
```

But how do I do it?

Comment: Exactly the same for all inputs you want, without the need to initialize other scanners, you can use the same scanner object for different inputs

Comment: Write more lines which use the same scanner. e.g. copy the last time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reuse the same scanner object:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 

String a = scanner.nextLine();

String b = scanner.nextLine(); // use the scanner object to get the next line
```

Comment: I have another problem, Since i am using the scanner with a switch case it won't do the 2nd scanner because of the break; in the switch case, how do i fix this?